# Loop recursively through multidimensional array and do something for every key value

Tags: php, arrays

I am building a generic database seeder, where based upon given input (array) some tables are seeded. Currently I have an array that is nested 1 level deep:

```
 $topics = [
     'Array value 1',
     'Array value 2',
     'Array key value 1' => [
          'Nested array value 1',
          'Nested array value 2',
     ],
     'Array key value 2' => [
          'Nested array value 3',
     ],
 ];
```

In my seeder I loop through this array of Topics. If the Topic is a key, it is a parent and I need to save its ID to assign it to the child. For example: the ID of 'Array key value 1' needs to be passed to 'Nested array value 1' because they are connected. The way I do this now is like this:

```
        // Define seeders.
        $topicSeeder = new TopicTableSeeder;
        $agendaPointSeeder = new AgendaPointTableSeeder;

        // Get all the Topics and create Agenda Points.
        foreach ($topics as $key => $topic) {

            // Check if Topic is an array.
            if (is_array($topic)) {
                // If Topic is a key, it is a Parent.
                if ($key) {
                    // Topic is Parent so set parentId to NULL and save own ID. 
                    $parentAgendaPointId = NULL;

                    // Execute Topic and Agenda Point seeders. 
                    $topicId = $topicSeeder->run($organizationId, $key);
                    $parentAgendaPointId = $agendaPointSeeder->run($parentAgendaPointId);                       

                }

                // If Topic is an array but not a key, it is a Child and gets the parentId. 
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($topic); $i++) {
                    $topicId = $topicSeeder->run($organizationId, $topic[$i]);
                    $agendaPointSeeder->run($parentAgendaPointId);
                }
            } else {
                // Topic isn't an array so it should have no Parent.
                $parentAgendaPointId = NULL;
                $topicId = $topicSeeder->run($topic);
                $agendaPointSeeder->run($parentAgendaPointId);
            }
        }
```

The problem is, when the array is nested more levels deep, the foreach in the code above doesn't work anymore. For example this array:

```
  $topics = [
     'Unnested topic',
     'Unnested topic 2',
     'Key topic' => [
          'Nested topic',
          'Nested topic 2',
     ],
     'Key topic 2' => [
           'Nested key topic' => [
               'Nested topic 3',
           ],
     ],
  ];
```

How can I make this recursive, but remain the ability to do something when it's a child value? Any ideas or suggestions are welcome because I'm a bit stuck now.

Comment: What is the exact question? Your code seems to lack a recursive call(or maybe the code shown is incomplete).  You say `but remain the ability to do something when it's a child value`, so you are correctly checking for `is_array()` there and detecting that the current topic is a parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function loop($topics, $organizationId) {

    $topicSeeder = new TopicTableSeeder;
    $agendaPointSeeder = new AgendaPointTableSeeder;

    foreach ($topics as $key => $topic) {

        if (is_array($topic)) {

            if ($key) {
                $parentAgendaPointId = null;
                $topicId = $topicSeeder->run($organizationId, $key);
                $parentAgendaPointId = $agendaPointSeeder->run($parentAgendaPointId);
            }

            loop($topic, $organizationId);
        }

        else {
            $parentAgendaPointId = null;
            $topicId = $topicSeeder->run($topic);
            $agendaPointSeeder->run($parentAgendaPointId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I know the `$topic` is a `child` now instead of just a 'normal' `topic`? Because I have to execute the seeder with different parameters if it is a `child`.

Comment: You can add third parameter `$child` with default value `false` and change the inner call to set it to `true`

Comment: That worked like a charm, but what if the `key` is a `child` as well? Like 'nested key topic' how would I check that?

Comment: You can pass as many parameters as you want. I don't understand your case clearly. If you want to have the depth of iteration, you can add `$depth` parameter, with default value `0`. In inner calls  pass `$depth + 1` to this parameter. You can pass the parent `key` as well if you want

Comment: For example: `function loop($topics, $organizationId, $parentKey=null) {`. Inner call: `loop($topic, $organizationId, $key);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do with this simple recursion function:

```
     function recursive($topics, $key, $level=0)
  {
      if(is_array($topics)) {
          foreach($topics as $key1 => $topic) {
              if(is_array($topic)) {
                  recursive($topic, $key1, $level+1);
              } else {
                  echo "level: $level key: $key value: $topic \n";

              }
          }
        }
  }
```

Comment: But how do I get the `ID` from the `parent` now? Because all the `children` are displayed as `$topic`?

Comment: How do I know the `$topic` is a `child` now instead of just a 'normal' `topic`?

Comment: i have edited the answer to get the key. please check. you can call initially with recurisive($topics, 0)

Comment: what do you mean by `normal` topic? ('Unnested topic',
     'Unnested topic 2', this two in your example?)

Comment: 'Array value 1' and 'Array value 2' are considered normal Topics. The nested ones are children and the keys are parents.

Comment: You can add another extra param `level` to identify the nesting level and i think if the nesting level 0 then those topics are 'normal'  topic ( as you are said :D)

Comment: That worked like a charm, but what if the `key` is a `child` as well? Like 'nested key topic' how would I check that?

Comment: you don't print the node with child but only the leaf of the array

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.
However:

```
<?php

 $topics = [
     '1',
     '2',
     '3' => [
          '1n',
          '2n',
     ],
     '4' => [
           '1n' => [
               '1nn',
            ],
        ],
  ];

function recursion($arr){
    foreach($arr as $key => $topic){
        if(is_array($topic)){
            recursion($topic);
            echo $key . " => elements: " . count($topic) . "\n";
        }else{            
            echo $topic . "\n";
        } 
    }       

}

recursion($topics);
```

Output is the following:

```
1 
2
1n
2n
3 => elements: 2
1nn
1n => elements: 1 
4 => elements: 1
```

`1, 2, 1n and 2n` are normal topics. `3` has two child elements (respectively `1n` and `2n`). `1nn` is normal topic and `1n` has one child (`1nn`) and 4 has one child (`1n`).

From another point of view, `4` is the father of `1n` that is the father of `1nn` and `3` is the father of `1n` and `2n`. `1` and `2` have no father, instead.

So, now you are able to know the schema of the nested array after recursion is applied and if an element is a normal child or not.